# Should I sell to Nook or Re-Tail?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I noticed that the nice people at Re-Tail buy my used goods/fish/bugs/misc. at a higher price than the Nook crime family will. In past games, however, you needed to have a combined buy/sell amount at Nook's (who is a seedy criminal) shop in order for the store to  upgrade.

Am I losing something or missing out if I buy from Nook's shop and sell to Re-Tail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Always, always sell to Re-Tail. They will always buy your items at a higher price than the Nook stores will.

While the Nookling store *does* upgrade in this game, they upgrade only based on the amount you have *spent* in their store, not the combined buy/sell amount. 
You can see all shop upgrades [here](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Timmy_and_Tommy%27s_store) and their requirements on their respective pages, where you can see that the only requirement is Bells spent.

So you're not missing out on anything if you buy from Nook's and sell to Re-Tail.

Comment: Also note the Nooklings even *tell* you that they'll give you a lower price than Re-Tail the first time you try to sell to them

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info! That`s exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Re-Tail gives you more money overall, but I've found that if you try to sell them beehives, they will charge you a fee while the Nook brothers will actually pay you 400 bells per beehive.